# What does byBatch(size) mean in SnappyDB?

Tags: android, snappydb

```
for (String[] batch : snappyDB.allKeysIterator().byBatch(0))
```

What does 'size' param mean in byBatch() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using `byBatch` you will only have a `KeyIterator` which does not implement `Iterator` or `Iterable` so you can't use it in a loop.

`byBatch(n)` creates a `BatchIterable` which is `Iterable` and an `Iterator`. It basically just calls `next(n)` on the `KeyIterator` when you call `next()` on it. ([Source](https://github.com/nhachicha/SnappyDB/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/snappydb/internal/KeyIteratorImpl.java#L89))

`KeyIterator#next(int max)` seems to always attempt to fetch `max` elements from the Database. So I presume you will most likely have `max` elements in the `batch` array from your example on each iteration. So it doesn't make much sense to pass `0` as you're doing (not sure if that even works).

---

Also just reading the README from the GitHub repo reveals [some documentation](https://github.com/nhachicha/SnappyDB#iterators):

```
Iterable<String[]> byBatch(int size); // Get an iterable of key batch, each batch of maximum [size] keys.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to SnappyDB documentation, found [here](https://github.com/nhachicha/SnappyDB):

`Iterable<String[]> byBatch(int size);// Get an iterable of key batch, each batch of maximum [size] keys.`

So size specifies the maximum number of keys for each batch. However, according to the documentation:

> Please note that you should use the byBatch iterable to process all
>   keys only on large collections. On reasonably small collections, using
>   the array based APIs (findKeys and findKeysBetween) with the form for
>   (String key : db.findKeys("android")) is a lot more efficient.
>   Iterators should only be used to process large collections or for
>   collection paging view / access.

So make sure that you really need byBatch in your use case.